# How to use tlhelp32 and NtQuerySystemInformation

Tags: c++, winapi, taskmanager

I work with C++Builder in RAD Studio. I have a new project, I need to make a task manager. I need to do it with the WinAPI. To get a list of processes, I hear I can use tlhelp32 or NtQuerySystemInformation().

How is this program done using the WinAPI?

Please give advice on where to start.

Comment: Your question is far too broad to fit SO. I suggest you search on the keywords you already know (e.g. `NtQuerySystemInformation`) and study those q/a for hints on how to proceed.

Comment: Okay, thanks about WinAPI, can you explain briefly?

Comment: I have done several projects, but I can’t understand how to use WinAPI

Comment: @Muhammed what exactly do you not understand about it? The Windows API is a set of libraries (DLLs) that apps can use. The documentation for each API function tells you which header to #include in your code, and which .lib to link against. Many documentations even provide code examples. There are numerous questions on StackOverflow explaining how to use Windows API functions in general.

Comment: Sample to get a list of processes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes